# Authentication and authorization - new to security

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication

Need to develop a Web application that will be used to authenticate and authorize internal and external users to log and then re-route to web applications for the organization. The login application should be able to provider smooth integration with any future applications that needs a secured authentication.

Should I be using WIF - Claims based Identity/ADFS or asp.net Role membership provider to develop this app.?  Or is there any other approach which will help achieve this?

Comment: So, .NET?  Can you give us a little more information about what language you're working with?

Comment: Asp.net(yet to decide -3.5/4.0?), C#

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on an asp.net site with WIF for several months now.  I like that WIF is very flexible, but the documentation is poor.  Check out the discussions on SO about WIF.